Why were the names of Western Roman emperors mostly unique?
During the classical antiquity most monarchs in Europe and the Middle East had some recurring names for their monarchs (e.g. Ptolemy in Egypt, Seleukos and Antiochios in the Seleucid empire, Hormizd and Shapur in the Sassanian Empire, Pilipp in the Macedonian empire)
In the Roman empire, especially the western Roman empire and the early eastern roman empire nearly all emperors had unique names. Only a few emperors had a name that was already used by a former ruler.
Is this a fluke, a coincidence, or were the Roman emperors opposed to using a name more than once? Maybe in order to not be compared to a former emperor?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

These unique names were invented by the later historians for convenience. The actual names were very far from unique and very confusing. See the answer below. Or you can check their official names with Wikipedia.

Summary of the answers below: they weren't.  False premise.  Numbers and nicknames are ways for people to distinguish between rulers in contexts where there might be confusion.

In many cases they were not very different, actually.  Historical practice over centuries have given them tags by which they are known, but those were not their full names or, indeed, their names at all.  From Wikipedia:List_of_Roman_emperors:
Known as: Actual regnal name

Augustus: Caesar Augustus
Tiberius: Tiberius Caesar Augustus
Caligula: Gaius Caesar Augustus Germanicus
Claudius: Tiberius Claudius Caesar Augustus Germanicus
Nero: Nero Claudius Caesar Augustus Germanicus
Galba: Servius Galba Caesar Augustus
Otho: Marcus Caesar Augustus
Vitellius: Aulus Vitellius Germanicus Augustus
Vespasian: Caesar Vespasianus Augustus
Titus Titus Caesar Vespasianus Augustus
Domitian: Caesar Domitianus Augustus
Nerva: Nerva Caesar Augustus
Trajan: Caesar Nerva Traianus Augustus
Hadrian: Caesar Traianus Hadrianus Augustus
Antoninus Pius: Titus Aelius  Hadrianus Antoninus Pius
Marcus Aurelius: Marcus Aurelius Antoninus
Lucius Verus: Lucius Aurelius Verus
Commodus: Marcus Aurelius Commodus Antoninus / Lucius Aelius Aurelius Commodus
Pertinax: Publius Helvius Pertinax
Didius Julianus: Marcus Didius Severus Julianus
Septimius Severus: Lucius Septimius Severus Pertinax
Caracalla: Marcus Aurelius Antoninus
Geta: Publius Septimius Geta
Macrinus: Marcus Opellius Severus Macrinus
Elagabalus: Marcus Aurelius Antoninus
Severus Alexander: Marcus Aurelius Severus Alexander


This, combined with an understanding of Roman Naming Conventions is a good answer.

This might be because OP is unclear, but none of these emperors were part of the Western Roman Empire, which only came into existence at the end of the fourth century. I presume this is what OP is referring to.

@cmw Is that situation different? Looking through the ones with regnal names on Wikipedia there's Flavius Honorius Augustus (Honorius), Flavius Claudius Constantinus (Constantine III), Flavius Constantius Augustus (Constantius III), and Flavius Placidus Valentinianus Augustus (Valentinian III)

@cmw Perhaps I should have continued, but it seemed tedious -- the only real variation comes during the crisis of the 3rd century.

@Nolimon It's not different. It's just that this answer doesn't address it. It wouldn't matter, except the question mentions the Western Roman Empire specifically, so I figured it would be useful to address, or even made the focus of the answer.

Oh for Pete's sake, you stopped just short of Gordian I and Gordian II!

A traditional Roman name has three parts: the "praenomen" (roughly corresponding to the Western "first name"), the "nomen" (roughly equivalent to the "last name"), and the "cognomen" (one or more nicknames, acquired or bestowed over the course of one's life).
The praenomen and nomen were strongly constrained by tradition, with the result that by the beginning of the Empire, only about a dozen praenomens and a few dozen nomens were in use by the aristocracy.  The usual way of distinguishing one person from another was through the combination of nomen and cognomen, such as "Julius (nomen) Caesar (cognomen)".
The reason why the names of Western Roman emperors appear to be unique is because you're only seeing a small part of the full name, typically the best-known cognomen.  The full names of the first five emperors, for example, are:

Gaius Julius Caesar Augustus
Tiberius Julius Caesar Augustus
Gaius Caesar Augustus Germanicus
Tiberius Claudius Caesar Augustus Germanicus
Nero Claudius Caesar Augustus Germanicus

Or for a more dramatic example from the Tetrarchy:

Gaius Aurelius Valerius Diocletianus
Marcus Aurelius Valerius Maximianus
Gaius Galerius Valerius Maximianus
Marcus Flavius Valerius Constantius
Flavius Valerius Severus
Valerius Licinianus Licinius
Galerius Valerius Maximinus
Aurelius Valerius Valens
Marcius Martinianus


In western European culture it eventually became the rule to number monarchs by their first name or personal names followed by a ordinal number: "the first", "the second", "the third", etc. and eventually to use Roman numerals for the numbers.
Suppose that Roman Emperors were described that way:
Augustus: Gaius I.
Tiberius: Tiberius I.
Caligula: Gaius II.
Claudius: Tiberius II.
Nero: Nero I.
Galba: Servius I or Lucius I.
Otho:  Marcus I.
Vitellius: Aulus I.
Vespasian: Titus I.
Titus: Titus II.
Domitian: Titus III.
Nerva: Marcus II.
Trajan: Marcus III.
Hadrian: Publius I.
Antoninus Pius: Titus IV.
Marcus Aurelius: Marcus IV.
Lucius Verus: Lucius I.
Commodus:           Lucius II or Marcus V.
Pertinax:           Publius II.
Didius Julianus:    Marcus V or Marcus VI.
Septimius Severus:  Lucius II or Lucius III.
Caracalla:          Lucius III or Lucius IV or Marcus VI or Marcus VII.
Geta:               Publius III.
Macrinus:           Marcus VII or Marcus VIII.
Diadumenian:        Marcus VIII or Marcus IX.
Elagabalus:         Sextus I or Marcus IX or Marcus X.
Severus Alexander:  Marcus X or Marcus XI.

Something similar would happen for, say, US Presidents, just because names are traditionally chosen from a rather limited pool.  George W Bush for example would been George III, Jimmy Carter would have been James VI, Bill Clinton would have been William IV, and JFK would have been John IV.

@MCW I actually don't think it's close. The question is why the (commonly used) names are unique, not "what would they be if they followed 'standard' conventions". -- That their "actual" name is different from what we know them as is part of it, but I an actual answer to the question would be why, for example, we know Gaius Caesar Augustus Germanicus as "Caligula" instead of some form of "Gaius" (or Caesar Nerva Traianus Augustus as Trajan, etc.). A good answer would also touch upon how his contemporaries would refer to him, and why that may or may not match up with how we refer to him.

@R.M. The New Testament provides a sample of what people in the provinces called the current Emperor: "If you let this man go, you are no friend of Caesar". John is actually talking about our friend Tiberius. Only dead emperors need names (and crappy emperors sometimes got posthumous names like "Bootikins"). All the average subjects needed to know about the emperor was that he was called "Caesar" and "Augustus", and that they had better obey him.

That's a quite interesting take on the naming convention.

I like this answer a lot..

Some names we now use were nicknames. "Caligula" was a belittling nickname given to an Emperor who was not held in high esteem. It's often translated as "Little Boots", though historian Mary Beard suggests that "Bootikins" is a better translation to show how belittling it was. Suffice it to say that nobody called him this to his face.

"Caracella" was a nickname for another unpleasant emperor, based on his habit of wearing a barbarian garment. Imagine calling a politician "Hoodie" or "Nike Jordan".
